# Which of the three Spanish "is" words should be used about the God's existence?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas

Which of the three Spanish *is* words (*ser*, *estar*, *haber*) should be used when talking about the God's existence?

And is there any difference between speaking about the existence of any (pagan) gods, or about the existence of the only God of the monotheistic religions?

Which is the correct Spanish *is* in the following sentences (and why)?

> 1. Is there a god?
> 2. Is there the God in the heaven?
> 3. There is no God, we are alone.

(The meaning of the sentence 2 is not asking the God's location!)

Is it analogical to talking about gas stations in the following example?

> 1. ¿*Hay una* gasolinera cerca de aquí?
> 2. ¿*Está la* gasolinera Repsol YPF cerca de aquí?

Note: I am aware of the existence of *existir* :) I am trying to understand better the difference between the three *to be* words.

Comment: You may add to your list the word _existir_ (unless you already have considered, of course).

Comment: @Rodrigo: I am aware of *existir*, but I am trying to understand better the difference between the three *to be* words - and this is a nice context to help understand.

Comment: One possible issue with this is that you'll enter a philosophical difference. The three words could be used to differentiate between three possible existences of God. In philosophical texts, the exact term used can change the meaning even if in common-day use they are synonyms. 

But this is not an answer and doesn't help you any further to be honest. Just thought that might be worth to take note of

Comment: @DylanMeeus: it may be quite interesting if you try to work out your comment as an answer with small explanation what philosophical meaning each of the 3 to-be-words would have. Plus adding what would common Spanish-speaking people chose in the common dialogs. Like in a pub discussion: "Do you believe in God?" "No, I personally think there is no God."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*haber* is used to talk about the existence of something, with that thing being a direct object.  So if you could imagine yourself rewriting with *existir*, then *haber* is generally what you'll want to use.  Note two small but important differences

1. the thing in question is the direct object with *haber*, but the subject with *existir*

   - *¿Hay unas manzanas por ahí?  Sí, **las** hay.*
   - *¿Exist**en** unas manzanas por ahí?  Sí, exist**en**<sub>(ellas)</sub>.*
2. *existir* can be used with definite or indefinite things, but *haber* requires indefinite

   - *¿Existe **la** fuente de la juventud?* <sub>(bien dicho)</sub>
   - *¿Existe **una** fuente de la juventud?* <sub>(bien dicho)</sub>
   - *¿Hay **la** fuente de la juventud?* <sub>(mal dicho)</sub>
   - *¿Hay **una** fuente de la juventud?* <sub>(bien dicho)</sub>

Notice that if you reference God (definite, e.g. *el Dios*) you won't be able to use *haber*.  But if referencing god(s), which can be used indefinitely, then you can use *haber*:

1. ¿Hay un <sub>(o *algún*)</sub> dios?
2. ¿Hay un <sub>(o *algún*)</sub> dios en el cielo?
3. No hay <sub>(*ningún*)</sub> dios<sub>/*es*</sub>, estamos solos.

You'll use *algún* to be more generic, otherwise, *hay un dios* means is there *one* god, as opposed to is there *a* god.  You'll generally want to use either *ningún* or pluralize *dios* unless you give other attributes.

You can use *ser* in the pronominal form *serse* to mean *haber/existir* but it's incredibly old fashioned and these days you only here it at to start a story: *érase una vez*, but you could theoretically — but I absolute do not recommend — say, for instance, *¿Se es un dios?* or *¿Esse un dios?*, neither of which would probably be recognized by most Spanish speakers today.

Notice the differences, though, if we use the other verbs:

- **ser**

  1. ¿Es un dios?
     <sup>Is he/she/it a god?</sup>
     ¿Es Dios? <sub>(note capitalization)</sub>
     <sup>Is it God?</sup>
     ¿Es (el/un) dios [adj./sust.]?
     <sup>Is the/a god [adj./noun]?</sup>
  2. *****¿Es el/un dios en el cielo?
     <sup>(not grammatical, unless we finish the sentence like, *¿Es el dios en el cielo un ser espiritual?* or something)</sup>
  3. No es Dios …
     <sup>He/she/it's not God</sup>
     No es ningún dios …
     <sup>He/she/it's no god …</sup>
     No es el Dios …
     <sup>He/she/it's not *the* God …</sup>
- **estar**

  1. ¿Está un dios?
     <sup>Is a god (here)?</sup>
     ¿Está Dios?
     <sup>Is God (here)?</sup>
     ¿Está el dios?
     <sup>Is the god here?</sup>
     ¿Está un dios [adj.]?
     <sup>Is a god [adj.]? (etcétera)</sup>
  2. ¿Está un/el dios en el cielo?
     <sup>Is a/the god in the sky/heavens?</sup>
     ¿Está Dios en el cielo?
     <sup>Is God in the sky/heavens?</sup>
  3. No está ningún/el dios …
     <sup>A/the god isn't (here) …</sup>
     No está Dios …
     <sup>God isn't (here) …</sup>

Also, you might want to note that there are other verbs that can be used to mean *to be*, including *tener*, *hacer*, and *resultar*.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Still I do not understand that: can you say *¿Hay Dios?* (capitalized, in the meaning of *Is there the (Christian) God?*) and *No hay Dios* in the meaning of *There is not such thing as the (Christian concept of) God*? Could you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @HonzaZidek no, you can't, because *Dios* is definite (you can't ask *¿Hay Juana?*, for instance). Other definite forms like *el dios*, *este dios*, *ese dios*, *aquel dios*, or *mi dios* — whether capitalized or not — cannot be used here because they all are definite). *un dios*, *algún dios*, *muchos dioses* are all indefinite, and could be used.

Comment: What sounds strange to me is that the atheist shall use different verbs for something which to me is exactly the same concept! To Christians: *No es Dios*. To pagans: *No hay dioses*.

Comment: Sorry, *No está ningún/el dios …* and *No está Dios* are just so wrong. Also the order in the questions `verb + subject` is rather Spanglish.

Comment: @c.p. how so? They are perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @guifa I cannot realize your *estar*-examples as something feasible. For instance, *no está la cerveza derramada sobre la nada* is as grammatial as your examples: but both seem to be nonsense.

Comment: @c.p. "¿Dónde están los dioses?" "Los dioses están en el monte Olimpo" "Pues no, ningún dios está en el monte Olimpo, todos están en el río Nilo".  ¿Sabes dónde está Dios?  Pues, Dios está en el cielo", "No, no está Dios en el cielo, está aquí en nuestros corazones".  Also, VSO is the *standard* question order in Spanish, so I'm not sure how you feel that makes them Spanglish.  Only Caribbean Spanish is generally known for SVO ("¿Cómo Vd. está?").

Comment: @guifa *¿Está un dios?* makes no sense, and if it would, it is not translated as "is there a god here?" You cannot use the verb *estar*, you must  use *existir* or *haber*. It doesn't base on grammar, and not any wrong sentences fails at grammar. Also: By itself, most of your sentences don't make sense, as you pointed out in the case *ser, 3*: "not grammatical, unless we finish the sentence". And no *No, no está Dios en el cielo....*  is not the right order, excepting, perhaps, the church. *¿Está Dios en el cielo?* should also be *¿Dios está en el cielo?*. And it woudn't be Caribean.

Answer (score -2):

We would use the verb ser. Ser is the verb used for existence "Dios es = God exists". When using "estar", it is used for the situation, the incident or the appearance.

Furthermore when we speak about the presence of God "God is here", would use the verb estar, though in medieval times the verb "ser" was used. (To indicate his omnipresence, and I don't think this is really wrong because of this reason).

Haber would be used when speaking about (the concept) god. Not God (The specific diety). But I fear that this might be different in Spanish use of the three verbs, and maybe even interchangeable as they don't attach a philosophical value to the words. But this is speculation of my part, a native Spanish speaker should correct me on this.

As for your three examples. I would use.

> 1. ¿Hay un dios
> 2. ¿Hay un dios en el cielo'
> 3. No hay dios (general gods).

About three, you can't say "There is no God" and talk about the specific entity, the sentence would not make sense. That sentence, when denying the existance of one specific god, would become something to the affect of "God does not exist", and then I would use the exister verb.

Comment: Disagree on number two. The correct form would be "¿Hay un Dios en el cielo?" If asking about his existence or "¿Está Dios en el cielo?" if asking about his location

Comment: @spiral that is actually in the answer, but I made a distinction between God and god. You seem to not make that distinction, and as I mentioned in my answer, I think many people would not necessarily make the distinction. I stand by my answer for number two though. (Note that your suggestion is in my answer, but does not mean the same thing)

Comment: @DylanMeeus it's not so much a question of a distinction between `[gG]ods?`.  *en el cielo* is a location, and thereby uses *estar*.  Portuguese would permit that use of *ser*, but not Spanish.

Comment: I would most certainly not use «¿Es Dios en el cielo?» for “Is there a God in heaven?”... I would use «¿Hay/existe un Dios en el cielo?»; also, in most variants of Standard American English, we don’t use  “the heaven,” with the article, unless it’s in plural (“the heavens”). We use “heaven is a beautiful place”/“God lives in heaven” and “the sky looks beautiful/he lives in the sky.”

Comment: It's an archaic construction. Ser was used for location in medieval Spanish. It would thus not surprise me to find it in a religious context. But I will remove that part from my answer. Thanks guys